# Implementing eachChild for a specefic case

Tags: javascript

I have a few places in my code that are very similar to this snippet:

```
tag_iter = hold_tags_el.firstChild;
do {
    if (tag_iter === null) {
        hold_tags_el.appendChild(paragraph_el);
        break;
    }
    if (par_el.innerHTML < tag_iter.innerHTML) {
        hold_tags_el.insertBefore(paragraph_el, tag_iter);
        break;
    }
    if (tag_iter === hold_tags_el.lastChild) {
        NS.insertAfter(tag_iter, paragraph_el);
        break;
    }
    tag_iter = tag_iter.nextSibling;
} while (tag_iter !== null);
```

This can be abstracted to:

```
tag_iter = ref_el.firstChild;
do {

    // loop logic

    tag_iter = tag_iter.nextSibling;
} while (tag_iter !== null);
```

---

In a function form this would look like:

The Call:

```
eachChild(par_el, function (tag_iter, par_el) {
    // loop logic
});
```

The Definition:

```
NS.eachChild = function (par_el, func, context) {
    var iter_el = par_el.firstChild,
        result;
    do {
        result = func.call(context, iter_el, par_el);
        if (result) {
            break;
        }
        iter_el = iter_el.nextSibling;
    } while (iter_el !== null);
}
```

Is there a library that implements this pattern / idiom?

What improvements can be made to `eachChild`?

Are there any errors in `eachChild`?

Applying the idiom we have:

**Snippet A**

```
NS.eachChild(el, function(tag_iter, par_el){
    // first
    if (tag_iter === null) {
        par_el.appendChild(paragraph_el);
        return true;
    }
    // middle
    if (par_el.innerHTML < tag_iter.innerHTML) {
        par_el.insertBefore(paragraph_el, tag_iter);
        return true;
    }
    // last
    if (tag_iter === hold_tags_el.lastChild) {
        par_el.appendChild(paragraph_el);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: In jQuery, that's as simple as `$('selector').children().each(function() { /* loop logic */ });`.

Comment: `NS.eachChild(el, function(){})`

Answer (score 2):

> What improvements can be made?

Many. Your snippet with its do-while loop and the many breaks is overly complicated and hard to understand. It can be simplified to

```
var tag_iter = hold_tags_el.firstChild,
    search = par_el.innerHTML;
while (tag_iter !== null && search >= tag_iter.innerHTML)
    tag_iter = tag_iter.nextSibling;
hold_tags_el.insertBefore(paragraph_el, tag_iter);
```

Notice that [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore) with `null` as second argument, `insertAfter(lastChild)` and `appendChild` do exactly the same thing.

With that simplification, you don't need that `eachChild` function any more. But maybe a little different one:

```
NS.findChild = function(parent, condition) {
    var child = parent.firstChild;
    for (var i=0; child!==null && condition(child, i); i++)
        child = child.nextSibling;
    return child;
};
// then simply:
var el = NS.findChild(hold_tags_el, function(tag_iter) {
    return tag_iter.innerHTML < par_el.innerHTML;
});
hold_tags_el.insertBefore(paragraph_el, el);
```

> Is there a library that implements this pattern / idiom?

I don't know any. But there are many libs with generic iterator methods (some of them with `break` functionality) that can easily be applied on `childNodes` collections.

> Are there any errors in eachChild?

It calls the callback even when there is no `firstChild` (with `null` as argument). That's at least unconventional, if not wrong - not what you would expect from an iteration. If you think to need it, this should better be made a separate case (a separate callback); otherwise it requires an extra condition in the callback. However in the given usecase you do not need it, as that is a *search* - see the `findChild` function above - where `eachChild` is inappropriate.

> What improvements can be made to `eachChild`?

Additionally to `parEl` maybe a counter argument might be nice - check the signature of the standard [`forEach` Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: @pure_code.mom: Well no problem in the simplified version this is just [one small change](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17346638/revisions#rev6e5247e4-8765-45ea-97f4-ca366abf4b03)…

Comment: In those special cases they should be bound to the callback from outer scope. If you think of it as a simplification to do the binding in your `eachChild`, then it should at least become an optional argument (in the end)

Comment: @pure_code.mom: The `while` loop does work because the element is inserted *after* it always. Try it. `insertBefore` can handle all of these cases.

Comment: `Many. Your snippet with its do-while loop and the many breaks is overly complicated and hard to understand. It can be simplified to..` - not relevant, that's why I posted this!! The idiom I wrote, has simpler syntax than jQuery and in my opinion is simpler to read...look at the updated question with the idiom applied...it has a simple start,middle, and end to account for the 3 cases of adding an element to a list.

Comment: first and last have the same body but can not combined b.c. of a special case of 2 items, and inserting one in the middle.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? To me, those "3 cases" are the same one. Does my simple loop work produce different results in one of these "special cases"?

Comment: Compare your answer to my snippet A and tell me honestly which one is easier to read first of all.

Comment: Well mine might be a little harder to read because of its conciseness (omitting the curly braces for example). But it definitely has the simpler control flow and it's easier to grasp *what it does*. And it gets even better with the `findChild` idiom. Could you elaborate what your snippet is *supposed to do* without referring to its 3 cases?